# Javascript Issues with Squarespace site

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add some javascript to my Squarespace site and it isn't working. I'm not sure if the code is correct or if it's just Squarespace.

Here are the two different codes that I'm trying to use:

```
<script src='http://www.adproval.com/widget/display_ads/1163.js' type='text/javascript'</script>
<div id='adproval-display-DS-38ff23ba6c73c8ccebb9ca5738503cfed38fe373'></div>


<script src='http://www.adproval.com/widget/ad_store/817.js' type='text/javascript'</script>
<div id='adproval-store-817'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing `>` for the opening `<script ...>` tag. Also `type` isin't a required attribute.

Try:

```
<script src='http://www.adproval.com/widget/display_ads/1163.js'></script>
```